# Order of effects on enemy frame

Tags: lancer-rpg

A Shredder Orochi Drone, the core system from the HORUS Hydra frame, has the following ability:

> As a reaction, you may force characters that start their turn adjacent to this drone or move adjacent to it for the first time in a round to make a Hull save. On a failure, they take 1 kinetic damage and become Shredded until the end of their next turn.

Shredded is:

> SHREDDED characters don’t benefit from ARMOR or RESISTANCE.

When the Shredder drone activates against a character with 1 or more armor, what order do the effects happen in?

If the effects happen in order they are listed in the ability, the mech takes zero damage (because of armor reduction), then the enemy is shredded, and armor is negated until their next turn.

If the effects happen in the opposite order (the order obviously more preferred by the Hydra pilot) the enemy mech is shredded first, negating their armor, and then they take one kinetic damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can apply the shred first.

According to the [Lancer rules FAQ](https://lancer-faq.netlify.app/#01d8e5), you can apply on-hit and on-crit effects in any order you choose. I don't see why this should be different for effects that apply on a failed save.

Here's that FAQ entry:

> **When I critically hit with a Chain Axe, does the Shredded effect apply before or after the weapon’s damage?**
>
> You can choose to apply on hit or on crit effects in whatever order you choose, including before damage from the attack in question. So when you critically hit with a Chain Axe you can choose to apply the Shredded condition to the target before dealing damage, preventing them from benefitting from armor or resistance.

Comment: I agree I don't see any reason that effects from a failed save would be different from on-hit or on-crit effects, but I also don't see a reference for the ruling given in the FAQ.  I'm already upvoting (and will probably accept, unless someone else comes along), but a reference to a page number (or even a searchable phrase for the pdf) would be fantastic.